# Sharing data between CXF interceptor and webservice

Tags: web-services, cxf, jax-ws, ws-security, wss4j

I'm using security interceptors with Apache CXF `WSS4JInInterceptor`.

Is there any way to pass data from interceptor to webservice?

I've been searching for that in `WebServiceContext` but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you looking to pass arbitrary data between your own extension of WSS4JInInterceptor and your service implementation?

Comment: My extension is a custom crypto instance that calls store procedures to get certificates from database, etc. Some data from SP must be available in my webservice implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CXF [Exchange](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Exchange.html) Map to store arbitrary key/value pairs.  The Exchange is available to both input and output messages.  In your interceptor, add the object to the Exchange, e.g.

```
Object value = ...;
message.getExchange().put("key", value);
```

Within your service, you can use [PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/phase/PhaseInterceptorChain.html#getCurrentMessage%28%29) to access the exchange and retrieve the object, e.g.

```
Object value = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().getExchange().get("key");
```

Comment: This response is correct, but I wrote the wrong question. Sorry for that I mistook the concepts. I need pass data from org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Crypto to webservice implementation. I will ask again. Thanks @Patrick

Comment: Is your class implementing Crypto inside CXF?  As long as the CXF message has been created, you should be able to add things to the exchange with PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().getExchange().put().  Otherwise, a ThreadLocal might be another option.

Comment: oh, you are right, I will try with PhaseInterceptorChain. Thanks ;)

Comment: I was able to access this context in a class that implements javax.security.auth.callback.Callback and was part of a wss4jInterceptor (org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor) and to share data between it and a spring interceptor class that implements org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor.MethodInterceptor. It works perfectly!