# Communication between cxf interceptors, listeners and webservice (jaxws)

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, interceptor

We have web service (jaxws) which is calling another web service (aslo jaxws). Jaxws client configuration looks like this  --

```
 <jaxws:client id="helloClient"
              serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"
              address="http://localhost:9002/HelloWorld" >
      <jaxws:outInterceptors>
             <bean class="com.company.MyOutInterceptor"/>
      </jaxws:outInterceptors>
      <jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
             <bean class="com.company.MyInFaultInterceptor"/>
      </jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
      <cxf:properties>
             <entry key="org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener">
                 <bean class="com.company.MyFaultListener"/>
             </entry>
      </cxf:properties>
 </jaxws:client>
```

As you can see we have two interceptors and one fault listener. We want to communication among these interceptors, fault listeners and web service code.
As given in [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184781/sharing-data-between-cxf-interceptor-and-webservice), we used cxf [Exchange](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Exchange.html) object for communication between web service and interceptor.

Our inFaultInterceptor code look like this --

```
public class MyInFaultInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>      {
      public MyInFaultInterceptor() {
           super(Phase.RECEIVE);
      }

      public void handleMessage(Message message) {
          message.getExchange().put("key", "value");
      }
```

}

Out web service code look like this --

```
public String addNumbers(int a, int b){
     try{
          myService.add(a,b);
     }catch(MyServiceException e){
          //Logging
     }
     Object value = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().getExchange().get("key");
}
```

But, int the web service code we are getting null for given "key", means "key" is not present.

> Is there any way in which we can communicate between interceptors and
>   web service?
>
> **P.S** : We are able to communicate within interceptors and listeners with the above method. That is, we are able to access key set in
>   outInterceptor in inFaultInterceptor, but keys set in any interceptor
>   or listener is not accessible in web service.

Comment: `PhaseInterceptorChain` is using a  `ThreadLocal` to store the message. Probably the Exchange Messsage is consumed and cleaned after interceptor chain finish and you can not recover it with `PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is any Cxf in built mechanism, I use `ThreadLocal` to pass information between webservice method and interceptor,

```
public final class KPContextHolder {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> myKey = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private KPContextHolder() {

    }

    public static String getMyKey() {
        return myKey.get();
    }

    public static void setMyKey(final String input) {
        myKey.set(input);
    }

    /**
     * Clear all the fields saved in the thread context
     */
    public static void clear() {
        myKey.remove();

     }

}
```

Interceptor class

```
  public class MyInFaultInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>      {
          public MyInFaultInterceptor() {
               super(Phase.RECEIVE);
          }

          public void handleMessage(Message message) {
              KPContextHolder.setMyKey("value");
          }
}
```

And WebService Method.

```
public String addNumbers(int a, int b){
     try{
          myService.add(a,b);
     }catch(MyServiceException e){
          //Logging
     }
     String value = KPContextHolder.getMyKey();
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. Once used you should explicitly clear the thread context else you would end up leaking memory